# Apache2 installation error

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Then I had an error with the PDO drivers and could't run my app I tried to fix the problem but then my apache2 crashed I tried to reinstall but without success. After several times, I deleted all files that show me the command **whereis apache2** Now everytime I install apache2 I have an error.

> **input:** sudo apt-get install apache2
>
> **output:** Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done The following additional packages
>   will be installed:   apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils Suggested
>   packages:   apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine |
>   apache2-suexec-custom The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils 0 upgraded, 4 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 923 kB/1253 kB
>   of archives. After this operation, 5383 kB of additional disk space
>   will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Get:1
>   http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64
>   apache2-bin amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1 [923 kB] Fetched 923 kB in 0s
>   (7352 kB/s)     Selecting previously unselected package apache2-bin.
>   (Reading database ... 327869 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   .../apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking apache2-bin
>   (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   apache2-utils. Preparing to unpack
>   .../apache2-utils_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Selecting previously unselected
>   package apache2-data. Preparing to unpack
>   .../apache2-data_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_all.deb ... Unpacking apache2-data
>   (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   apache2. Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Processing triggers for
>   man-db (2.7.5-1) ... Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7)
>   ... Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ... Processing
>   triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ... Processing triggers for gitweb
>   (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1) ... Package apache2 is not configured yet. Will
>   defer actions by package gitweb. Setting up apache2-bin
>   (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1)
>   ... Setting up apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Setting up apache2
>   (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ... Enabling module mpm_event. Enabling module
>   authz_core. Enabling module authz_host. Enabling module authn_core.
>   Enabling module auth_basic. Enabling module access_compat. Enabling
>   module authn_file. Enabling module authz_user. Enabling module alias.
>   Enabling module dir. Enabling module autoindex. Enabling module env.
>   Enabling module mime. Enabling module negotiation. Enabling module
>   setenvif. Enabling module filter. Enabling module deflate. Enabling
>   module status. Enabling conf charset. Enabling conf
>   localized-error-pages. Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log. Enabling
>   conf security. Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin. Enabling site 000-default.
>   **info: Executing deferred 'a2enconf gitweb' for package gitweb ERROR:
>   Conf gitweb does not exist! dpkg: error processing package apache2
>   (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
>   error exit status 1 Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
>   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ... Processing
>   triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ... Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  apache2 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
>   code (1)**

The error is bolded. 
I can't run my apps local.

Comment: dpkg failed attempting to install gitweb ... fix your gitweb build (e.g. install it) and try again.

Comment: I almost fixed the problem with the answers here http://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser Now just should found why the php files are not parsing

Comment: Apache config ..  AddModule, AddHandler, & restart httpd.